# Why doesn't Logic Apps Schedular work with a WHEN HTTP REQUEST IS RECEIVED?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In Azure Logic Apps, if we create a trigger (when HTTP Request is received) - still why can't I add a schedular to execute that trigger? In Logic apps, it doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**When a HTTP request is received**" trigger is used to request the url to trigger the logic app, but not as a "**schedule**" triggered every a while. We can just trigger the logic app by request the url manually (such as in postman, shown as below screenshot).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but why can't i create a SCHEDULE that executes that trigger???

Comment: @houba You can create a "Schedule" in a logic app and then use a "HTTP" action to request url of another logic app(which use "When a HTTP request is received").

Comment: @houba If you want to use both "Schedule" and  "When a HTTP request is received" in one logic app. It can't be implemented, because "Schedule" and "When a HTTP request is received" are trigger but not action, one logic app can only have one trigger with multiple actions.

Comment: @houba Use "HTTP" action to request another logic app's url(the second logic app uses "When a HTTP request is received" as trigger). You can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http) to use "HTTP" action.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a workaround for that, create 2 logicApps:

- first with HttpTrigger
- second with schedule, and here just add Http request to your first logicApp

doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence